# kpartx: cannot unmount disk after mappings have been deleted

Tags: shell, mount, lsof, loop-device, kpartx

I cannot unmount a partition on which I created and then deleted mappings with `kpartx`:

```
# mount /dev/sdb1 usb/
# cd usb/

# kpartx -a -p sda -r -s -v sda.img
add map loop0sda1 (254:5): 0 16777216 linear 7:0 2048
add map loop0sda2 (254:6): 0 16777216 linear 7:0 16779264
add map loop0sda3 (254:7): 0 440401920 linear 7:0 33556480
add map loop0sda4 (254:8): 0 26159792 linear 7:0 473958400

# kpartx -dv /dev/loop0
del devmap : loop0sda4
del devmap : loop0sda3
del devmap : loop0sda2
del devmap : loop0sda1

# cd ..
    
#umount usb/
target is busy.
```

as far as i can tell, the command  `kpartx -dv /dev/loop0` properly deleted the mappings, as I can see they have disappeared from `/dev/mapper/`. But still I cannot unmount the disk, because it reports: `target is busy.`

`lsof` shows no files open from that disk:

```
# lsof +D
```

Why cannot i unmout the disk after all mappings have been freed up ?

Comment: When I delete kpartx mappings I point to the file, matching your case: `kpartx -dv sda.img`. Maybe try that? Or maybe run `partprobe` or check if something is left in `/etc/mtab`.

Comment: @sudodus - when I do  `kpartx -dv sda.img`, nothing happens. It does not disassociate the mappings.

Comment: I don't use `-p sda` but it should be OK. Anyway, I have no more ideas. Let us hope that someone with more experience of `kpartx` will see your question and chip in to help :-)

Answer (score 5):

The second command isn't exactly the reverse of the first command because of the loop device given as parameter instead of the block image file which triggered initially the creation of this loop device.

If you then run:

```
losetup -l /dev/loop0
```

chances are you'll get this output:

```
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE            DIO LOG-SEC
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  1 /path/to/usb/sda.img   0     512
```

This keeps a resource tied with `sda.img` file and thus on the filesystem providing it, preventing unmounting it.

In this state, to free the leftover resource simply do:

```
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

---

### What should have been done?

```
 kpartx -dv /path/to/usb/sda.img
```

which should give this time:

```
del devmap : loop0sda4
del devmap : loop0sda3
del devmap : loop0sda2
del devmap : loop0sda1
loop deleted : /dev/loop0
```

Comment: `kpartx -dv /path/to/usb/sda.img` has no effect. It does not remove the mappings at all. But using the combination of `kpartx -dv /dev/loop0` and `losetup -d /dev/loop0` does work. But I wonder what the correct command would be to do it using `kpartx`

Comment: If you have /dev/loop0 as leftover, then it's too late to use kpartx -d, it won't know there's work to do. It has to be done instead of `kpartx -dv /dev/loop0`, not after it. If you indeed did it instead and not after, then it appears your version has a bug, since my version behaves as I wrote, ending with `loop deleted : /dev/loop0`. Just in case, use an absolute path both when creating the mappings and when removing them. Not half with a relative path, half with an absolute path.